# Determine value of X with specific conditions?

Tags: probability

Lindsay and Simon want to play a game in which the expected amount of
money that each of them wins is equal to zero. After having chosen a number x, the game
is played as follows: Lindsay rolls a fair die, independently, three times.

• If none of the three rolls results in 6, then Lindsay pays one dollar to Simon.

• If exactly one of the rolls results in 6, then Simon pays one dollar to Lindsay.

• If exactly two rolls result in 6, then Simon pays two dollars to Lindsay.

• If all three rolls result in 6, then Simon pays x dollars to Lindsay.

Determine the value of x.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By counting outcomes and multiplying them by probability and payoff, the expected payoff for Simon (and hence the negative of the expected payoff for Lindsay) is:

$$1 \cdot (5/6)^3 - 1 \cdot 3(1/6)(5/6)^2 - 2\cdot 3(1/6)^2(5/6) - x \cdot (1/6)^3$$

If you set this to zero you can solve for $x$.